# konica hexar upgrade

Tags: film, diy, upgrade, konica

I found this lovely old [konica hexar](https://www.cameraquest.com/konhex.htm) in a drawer.

It's already a pretty cool camera, but I found out it can be even cooler. The later versions have some extra features and konica used to offer a service to upgrade the older versions with these as well.

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konica_Hexar#cite_note-cq_hexar_af-1) that this upgrade can be performed by the user as well, but I have not been able to find instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently all the info is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080515153503/http://photo.net/photo/hexar.html). I don't have time right now to decrypt/declutter/re-type it, so I'll just leave the link here as a comment. By the way, the Internet Archive is a fantastic source of historical information. Consider donating.

Comment: @osullic, nope.  You need [a later capture of that photo.net page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130428135742/http://photo.net/photo/hexar.html) to get to the comments that outline steps for specific features (2003-2004), according to [this rangefinderforum post](https://www.rangefinderforum.com/forums/showpost.php?p=634000&postcount=13).